# configuring virtual machines

Tags: linux, windows-7, operating-systems, virtualization

I Have windows 7 and I installed one virtual machine in it and in this virtual machine I installed opensuse Linux

```
Virtual A-------------Linux(Virtual C)--------Virtual B
```

I want linux to be in the middle of two virtual machines then when I send file from virtual A to virtual B,in linux by scripts of TC(traffic controller) I can audit and see shaping,making leaky bucket,...

I should have 3 virtual machines to reach this goal but i'm not sure am i right?
and suppose I installed them
I don't know how to configure ports and network cards and IP addresses 
is there any references which is valuable in this subject?
or can anyone give me guidance?

Answer (score 1):

First you set up two virtual machines. 
Then you set up the third virtual machine as a router. (This VM needs two network adapters to look in two networks).

set up the router as follows. 
NIC A. For example: 192.168.1.1/24
NIC B. For example: 192.168.5.1/24

Then configure your virtual machines one for each network.
VM A: 192.168.1.5/24 default gw: 192.168.1.1
VM B: 192.168.5.5/24 default gw: 192.168.5.1

Then ping from 192.168.1.5 to 192.168.5.5 and sniff on your router.